# How to set text normal in <i> tag by css

Tags: html, css

I need to set text is normal in div tag:

```
._div
{
text-decoration:none;
}

<i>italic<div class="_div">need to unitalic</div></i>
```

But it's not works. How can I do this?

Comment: W3Schools isn't really popular on this site, but look at their [CSS Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/#font), it might help you later.

Comment: Unless you specifically need a block-element there. Don't put a DIV (block) inside your i-tag (inline). It's bad form and will break your HTML validation. Use span-tag if you want it to flow as normal text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
._div
{
 font-style: normal;
}
```

Edit: (comments) Since you can't override the line-through of the s tag you can make it look like you are overriding it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>

s {display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 100%;}

s ._div
{
 text-decoration:none ;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
</style>

<s>line-through <span class="_div">need to un-line-through</span></s>
</body>
</html>
```

you will need to adjust this to your layout (e.g width)

Comment: It's works,if I use <s> replace <i>. how can I get normal text in div?

Comment: @OnRacing You can't override a strikethrough

Answer (score 0):

if you use s tag u need add

```
<style>
s{
text-decoration : none !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
._italics {
font-style:italic;
}

<span class="_italics">italic</span> <div> need to unitalic </div>
```

If you want a striked text change the contents of class to

```
text-decoration:line-through
```